# Como tirar o foco de um button?

Tags: jquery

Tenho um button e o mesmo após o click gostaria de retirar o foco utilizando 
javascript, detalhe não utilizo o mouse utilizo este botão em uma tela 
touch, sem mouse ou teclado. 
Utilizo a seguinte função hoje para subir e descer a tela:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#up').click(function(){
         $('html, body').animate({scrollTop : $(window).scroll().scrollTop()-500},800);
    });   

    $('#down').click(function(){
         $('html, body').animate({scrollTop : $(window).scroll().scrollTop()+500},800);
    });
});
```

Preciso que além disto o button clicado fique sem foco.

Comment: Já testaste `$(this).blur()` dentro do event handler?

Comment: Sim testes o $(this).blur() não funciona para este caso.

Comment: @CatanaRahmeier, você gostaria de tirar o foco por uma questão estilo (o btn está com a borda), ou está atrapalhando na funcionalidade ?

Comment: Uma possibilidade seria setar o foco para outro campo.

Comment: Gostaria de alterar mais por uma questão de estilo mesmo. Setar o foco para outro campo é uma possibilildade, vou tentar isto na segunda, obrigada...